# Moment.js and Unix Epoch Conversion

Tags: javascript, date, epoch, momentjs

I have a web service that is returning a date as the following string:

`/Date(1377907200000)/`

I use MomentJS to parse this to a `moment` object.

`moment("/Date(1377907200000)/")` => `Fri Aug 30 2013 20:00:00 GMT-0400`

All of that is fine. But when I call `unix()` on the object I am given the value `1377907200`. This, however, corresponds to `Fri Jan 16 1970 17:45:07 GMT-0500`. I could just multiply the value returned by `unix()` but that seems sloppy to me. I suspect that what I am doing by calling `unix()` is not exactly what I think it is. Do I need to specify some sort of format when calling `unix()`? What am I missing here?

[JSFidle showing the conversion to moment and then back.](http://jsfiddle.net/RobertKaucher/CqrLA/)

Comment: You don't need to convert to the date object that way, moment can handle `moment(1377907200000)` just fine. Curious why the web service returns the date as such.

Comment: We use a web service that returns it as well-- this is because the target consumer of the API is usually JavaScript, which does "from Epoch in milliseconds" instead of seconds. It's targeted to the most likely consumer.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The answer provided by meagar is correct, from strictly a JavaScript / Unix time perspective.  However, if you just multiply by 1000, you will loose any sub-second precision that might have existed in your data.

Moment.js offers two different methods, as described [in the docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-offset/).  `.unix()` returns the value in seconds.  It is effectively dividing by 1000 and truncating any decimals.  You want to use the `.valueOf()` method, which just returns the milliseconds without modification.

Comment: Thanks for the additional details. At least for this item that would not be needed as the granularity is just to a day.

Comment: Oh, actually, I see that gives exactly what I expected. I would rather not modify the value in any way so your answer in fact is ideal.

Comment: sorry, but what object does `.valueOf()` get called on?

Comment: @chovy - It's a method on any `moment` object, such as `moment().valueOf()`

Comment: @MattJohnson thanks for this insight! been banging my head exactly about this problem! :-)

Answer (score 11):

In JavaScript land, when you convert a `Date` to an integer, you get a number of *milli*seconds since the unix epoch. Traditional Unix time is the number of *seconds* since epoch. Multiplying by 1000 is the correct option.

Comment: Or just `moment("/Date(1377907200000)/").toDate().getTime()`

Answer (score 0):

this solution help me to add the format to Epoch date using moment.js.

```
moment(1377907200000).format("DD MMM YYYY hh:mm A")
```